# What is the difference between "-copy" and "-copyWithZone:"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, foundation, nscopying

I know that copy creates an immutable copy of an object but i just want to know how copywithzone works and what is the basic difference between copy and copywithzone

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`copy` is just short for `copyWithZone:`, using the default zone.

it's rare that you would call `copyWithZone:` directly, although defining/implementing it is required in order to adopt `@protocol NSCopying`. so you would normally see `copyWithZone:` only within an implementation of `copyWithZone:`. similarly, you would typically avoid implementing `copy`, and just let the default implementation of `copy` call through `copyWithZone:`.

Answer (score 5):

`NSZone` is a legacy concept that has no bearing on iOS. By default `-copy` on an `NSObject` will call `-copyWithZone:` with the default zone.